# Webscraping Analytics Vidhya to get the courses and their names and total count of reviews

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have scraped analytics vidhya website to get their courses,names of courses and total reviews of their courses. There was no problem to get their coures however I am having trouble to scrape/get the names of courses and their total reviews.

here's my code:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    for page in range(1,5):
        url = "https://courses.analyticsvidhya.com/collections?category=courses&page="+str(page)
        page_request = requests.get(url)
        data = page_request.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
        for courses in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'collections__product-cards collections__product-cards___0b9ab'}):
            for course_name in soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'products__list'}):
                for names in soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'products__list-item'}):
                    for divs in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'course-card__body'}):
                        for revs in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'course-card__reviews'}):
                            reviews = soup.find('span', {'class': 'review__stars-count'})
                    title = soup.find('h3')
                    review = reviews.text
                    course_title = title.text
                    print(course_title + " "+str(review) +" "+ "https://courses.analyticsvidhya.com"+ names.find('a')['href'])
```

The problem while running this python script is that it keeps giving the same 'course_title'(name of the course) as well as the reviews.

Comment: You're using `title = soup.find('h3')` which will only pull one title per page. `titles = soup.find_all('h3')` will retrieve a list of all course titles. I need to step away for a few hours but if you need more help after that I can get back on it.

Comment: @JosephRajchwald thanks for your quick response, earlier i had tried ``` title=soup.find_all('h3') ``` but it throws a AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: `find_all` produces a _list_ of html. So you need to loop through each entry and then you can call the text method on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for page in range(1,6):
    url = "https://courses.analyticsvidhya.com/collections?category=courses&page="+str(page)
    page_request = requests.get(url)
    data = page_request.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
    for courses in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'collections__product-cards collections__product-cards___0b9ab'}):
        for names in courses.find_all('li', {'class': 'products__list-item'}):
             for divs in names.find_all('div', {'class':'course-card__body'}):
                    title = divs.find_all('h3')
                    for revs in divs.find_all('div', {'class': 'course-card__reviews'}):
                        rev=revs.find_all('span', {'class': 'review__stars-count'})
                    for i,j in zip(title,rev):
                        title =i.text
                        review=j.text
                        print(title + " "+str(review) +" "+ "https://courses.analyticsvidhya.com"+ names.find('a')['href'])
```

I have done a few edits on the code, now it is able to **scrape** course name, review content and the link.
[image]

Comment: Hey Sebin that worked great. thanks a ton. I understood where I was going wrong, thank you so much for your help!!